# How to set Documents mode Quirks in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, .net

i am using IE 10 and i  want to make Document mode of browser set to normal Quirks not IE 5 quirks of my website.I put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10;IE=9;IE=edge">` in my master page but no luck,Can anybody share your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have included the doctype at the top of your master page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If the browser supports the above tag(**HTML5**),It will make the browser to render the page at its highest version.

And the meta tag should be like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,9,edge">
```

IE9 and below versions will render the page to IE5.5 version in Quirks mode.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)